# Convert. Int64 or int.Parse Is Not Recognized LINQ To Entities

Tags: c#, string, entity-framework, range

I am trying to get range data between two strings.

i have list of string which have data like this

**Example:**

```
K123456,
H123456,
J123456,
T122123,
```

So the first charter of string object contains an alphabet.

```
var StartLabwareid = int.Parse(obj.LWbStartId.Replace(labIni,""));
var EndtLabwareid = int.Parse(obj.LWbEndId.Replace(labIni, ""));



var LabWId = (from ai in _entities.Ai
              join result in _entities.Re on ai.Id equals re.Id
              where (Convert.ToInt32(ai.Id.Replace(Ini,"")) <= Startid ||
                     Convert.ToInt32(ai.Id.Replace(Ini, "")) >= Endtid)
              select new MViewModel
              {
                  ID = re.Id,
              }).ToList();
```

Or I can use something else to compare to string and get data between that as we do in date range St rating and Ending Date

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're doing here, what is `Ini` and `labIni`? Can you give us an example of your start and end parameters and which rows you would like to return? The comparison parts also looks odd because it seems your SQL is retrieving rows *not* in that range, contrary to your description. Please be more specific in your question and example.

Comment: Since this is LINQ to Entities, what ever you are doing in you LINQ statement has to be translatable to SQL, so you are fairly limited in what you can use in your statement.

Comment: labIni is the starting charter of id example "K1234" so Labini is K

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use C# functions such as `Convert` in Linq to Entities. Instead, you could do your comparison after the result is materialized, or use `SqlFunctions`. With `SqlFunctions`, you should get your result with combining [Stuff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stuff(v=vs.110).aspx) and [CharIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487160(v=vs.110).aspx) functions. Modify the line below to suit your needs, since you are not providing all of the code.

```
SqlFunctions.Stuff(ai.Id, SqlFunctions.CharIndex(ai.Id, "replaceable"), 3, "")
```